# How to retrieve a single value from a listview

Tags: c#, wpf

Brand new to C sharp so forgive me is this is a stupid question.
I have a simple class:

```
    public enum SexType { Male, Female };
        public class User
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int Age { get; set; }

            public string Mail { get; set; }

            public SexType Sex { get; set; }
        }
```

Then I use the class to fill a list view by grouping.

```
public Window4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<User> items = new List<User>();
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Sex = SexType.Male });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Sex = SexType.Female });
            items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13, Sex = SexType.Male });
            lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

            CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Sex");
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

        }
```

Now all I want to be able to do is when a group is selected in the listview I want to be able to grab the individual items valuses. So if I clicked on the "John Doe" group in the listview I want to be able to get the Age(42) and Name(John Doe).
So I went to the SelectedChanged method for the listview but when I select a record in the listview I can't get the individual values.
When the SelectedChange fires and open the Immediate Window and if I look at ?listview.SelectedValue I get:
    {ListBoxSampleWPF.User}
        Age: 13
        Mail: null
        Name: "Sammy Doe"
        Sex: Male
    So I know the values are there but if I try:
    ?lvUsers.SelectedItems.Age;
    I get:
'System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'Age' and no extension method 'Age' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, this error comes because you trying to fetch your class property from list. Try following

```
var obj=lvUsers.SelectedItems[0] as User;
if(obj!=null)
{
   var age=obj.Age;
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I get this error:'object' does not contain a definition for 'Age' and no extension method 'Age' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Edit my answer. please check it